# Django translation: can't find msguniq

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

I would like to do the translation inside Django application.

I was following the [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nolanphillips/a-short-intro-to-translating-your-site-with-django-1-8-343ea839c89b) but I run into problems.

After I run the code

```
python manage.py makemessages -l 'de'
```

I get the error

```
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

The weird thing is, that I have the gettext already installed

```
Warning: gettext 0.19.8.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 0.19.8.1, run `brew reinstall gettext`
```

I have the settings set as:

```
# Translations
# Provide a lists of languages which your site supports.
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)
# Set the default language for your site.
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
# Tell Django where the project's translation files should be.
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
print(LOCALE_PATHS)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Do anyone know what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using django-admin:

`django-admin makemessages -l de`

Do you have in symlinked?

`brew link gettext --force`

Also, when I installed it on brew, there were a few extra steps. Did you do those?

- I'm updating .zshrc, but if you use bash, it would be, say, .bashrc

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include
`export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib`
`export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include`

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can run `msguniq` manually:

```
$ msguniq --help
```

If that gives you a command not found error, ensure that your `PATH` environment variable is set correctly for brew.

Comment: Yes, the msguniq --help get me not found error. How to fix the PATH?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the command without the quotes around the language?

```
python manage.py makemessages -l de
```

[django `makemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages)